# Storing data from user input into separate table scenes based on a specific category

Tags: swift, xcode, sorting, uitableview

Problem to solve:
Trying to pass data (`UITextField's`, `UITextView`, `UIPickerView` and an `UIImageView` from camera/library) to be stored permanently in specific `UITableViews` dependant on a variable.

Set up:
A `UICollectionView` houses images in cells of the available variable options, and when the user clicks on the Cell, a segue takes them to the `UITableView` scene for that category. I have only a `UITableView` with empty prototype content on my storyboard, not one scene for each variable. The segue for the above action is all in code.

In a separate `UIViewController`, the user identifies the variable I would like to use as a method to arrange how to get the information to the relevant `UITableView` scene. Simultaneously, the user enters information from `UITextField's`, a `UIPickerView` (with the variable), a `UITextView` and an `UIImageView`. I would like to get all of this information to the relevant `UITableView` scene, dependent on variable and to save permanently.

I have a button with no current function on this page ready to start off the action, but my novice ability has me scuppered at how to approach most efficiently.

Comment: You need to define what your data is and create structure for it, like classes or structs for model objects and arrays or similar to hold your model objects.

Comment: Thanks Jaokim. My data is entirely text, other than the one image. How would I go about defining what my data is please?